# Install phpmyadmin on centos vps hosting

Tags: centos

I'm trying to install phpmyadmin on centos vps hosting. I have uploaded all the phpmyadmin files in /usr/share/phpmyadmin as it was said in a tutorial but now when I enter http://mysite.com/phpmyadmin I get 404 error message. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not enough just to upload files to `/usr/share/phpmyadmin`.
There are several ways to install it:

1. The easiest way is to install it via yum (I don't use centos since centos 5 is release, but I hope it is still via yum)
2. Hard way is to install manually. Installation contains of several steps: 
   2.a. Dowanload and unpack files is /usr/share/phpmyadmin` (already done) 
   2.b. Add alias in your http daemon config. In case you're using apache, just put in your /etc/httpd/conf.d/phpmyadmin.conf  something like that:

```
# phpMyAdmin default Apache configuration

Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/share/phpmyadmin

<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    DirectoryIndex index.php

    <IfModule mod_php5.c>
            AddType application/x-httpd-php .php

            php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off
            php_flag track_vars On
            php_flag register_globals Off
            php_admin_flag allow_url_fopen Off
            php_value include_path .
            php_admin_value upload_tmp_dir /var/lib/phpmyadmin/tmp
            php_admin_value open_basedir /usr/share/phpmyadmin/:/etc/phpmyadmin/:/var/lib/phpmyadmin/
    </IfModule>

</Directory>

# Authorize for setup
<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin/setup>
    <IfModule mod_authn_file.c>
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "phpMyAdmin Setup"
    AuthUserFile /etc/phpmyadmin/htpasswd.setup
    </IfModule>
    Require valid-user
</Directory>

# Disallow web access to directories that don't need it
<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from All
</Directory>
<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin/setup/lib>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from All
</Directory>
```

And restart apache.

In case you're using another httpd or there is front-end+back-end solution just watch in your daemons manuals.

Hope it helps.